# rsync works one way but not the other

Tags: linux, rsync, linux-networking

I have a problem with using rsync. When I try to copy a remote file I get the following error:

```
[home ~]$ rsync test.txt qnx:
sh: rsync: cannot execute - No such file or directory
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Which i have searched and cannot find a specific solution. The weird part is that if I do it from the other side ie:

```
[home ~]$ ssh qnx
Welcome to QNX Neutrino!
Wed Feb  5 13:01:00 2014 on /dev/ttyp1
benqnx:/root# rsync test1.txt fedora:
uqbdart@10.33.4.242's password:
```

and the file test1.txt appears on the other side. What is the problem here?

Comment: As far as you don't specify the target user, your source system will use, by default, the current source user as the destination user. Try to either specify the target user : `rsync test.txt  user@qnx:` or create the user on the target.

Comment: It isn't that, I have a hosts file to setup qnx. I figured it out now, it was to do with QNX rather then the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Rsync needs to be installed on both systems. On QNX the ssh functionality is a problem as only the items in /bin can be used. After creating a symbolic link in /bin/ linking /usr/pkg/bin/rsync the system worked.